# What software should I use to solve systems of polynomial equations in many variables where every polynomial but one is homogeneous of degree 2?

Tags: polynomials

What software (or what theory) should I use to solve systems of polynomial equations in many variables where every polynomial is homogeneous of degree 2 and then there is an inequality?  The equations all have the form "polynomial = 0". The inequality has the form "polynomial $\ne$ 0".

I want to impose a condition that two specific variables have to be non-zero.

I don't necessarily need all of the solutions: I would just like some that are not "simple".  (I use that word instead of "trivial" in case "trivial" has a technical definition.)  For example, it would be nice to have a solution where none of the variables are 0.

But I suspect that with the system of equations (and the inequality) I have, there will be no solutions (except maybe "simple" ones), and I want to know how I can determine that.

I am willing to work over the integers.

If this is too vague, I can be more specific.

Comment: You might try Mathematica's functions "Reduce" or "FindInstance".

Comment: Every polynomial equation can be rewritten as a (finite) set of polynomial equations of degree $2$ by introducing additional variables. The restriction to degree $\leq 2$ is therefore helpless.

Comment: @RolandBacher, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/451315/what-software-should-i-use-to-solve-systems-of-polynomial-equations-in-many-vari#comment1166840_451315), how do you constrain the new variables in terms of the old ones using only degree-$2$ equations?

Comment: @LSpice If $x_ix_j$ occurs in a monomial of degree larger than 2, set $w_{i,j}=x_ix_j$ and replace $x_ix_j$ by the new variable $w_{i,j}$. This leads eventually to a system containing only polynomials of degree at most $2$ but involving (many) more variables.

Comment: To make it homogeneous, use $x_ix_j=w_{i,j}z$ (with the same $z$ in all equations). To make sure any nontrivial solution has $z\ne0$ (which can be scaled to $z=1$ by homogeneity), introduce for each original variable $x_i$ a new variable $v_i$, and add the equation $zv_i=x_i^2$.

Comment: Also, note that an inequality $p_i\ne0$ can be replaced with an equality $u_ip_i=1$ for a new variable $p_i$ (before the transformation to homogeneous degree $2$, as above).